# MVC autocomplete appending result in sentence

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm trying to make a textbox give suggestions for autocompletion of usernames in a textbox in MVC. The autocompletion part works, but I can't seem to have it just append the username to the sentence instead of replacing it completely!

I'm not very comfortable in Jquery/javascript, so I'm trying to do as much as I can in C#, but I think I'm now at a roads end with that.. I'm using the jquery-ui-1.11 autocomplete function after an example found here: [Autocomplete tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/746697/Auto-Complete-TextBox-Using-jQuery-and-ASP-NET-MVC)

this is the Jquery autocomplete script:

```
    $(".newpostbox").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var customer = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Home"))",
            data: { "term": request.term },
            minLength: 2,
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                    customer[i] = { label: data[i].Second, Id: data[i].First};
                }
            }
        });
        response(customer);
    }
});
```

I thought I was being smart using a Triplet to send the value/id, so I actually have the desired "first part of the sentence" in data[i].Third. So close!

I don't know if seeing the controller is important, but I'll post it anyways:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Autocomplete(string term) {

    //split string
    string[] dividers = { " ", ".", ",", "!", "?", "\n", "\r\n" };
    string[] splits = term.Split(dividers, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int index = splits.Length - 1;
    //look for @ signs
    if(index >= 0 && splits[index].Length > 1 && splits[index][0] == '@') {
        string impoterm = splits[splits.Length - 1].Substring(1);
        int end = term.Length - 1;
        do {
            end--;
        } while(end >= 0 && term[end] != '@'); 
        string beginning = term.Substring(0, end);

        //get names from DB
        StaticTagsContext tagdb = new StaticTagsContext();
        var tags = from a in tagdb.StaticTags where a.Name.Contains(impoterm) select a;
        List<StaticTag> taglist = tags.ToList();
        var names = new List<Triplet>();
        //IMPORTANT PART I GUESS 
        for(int i = 0; i < taglist.Count(); i++) {
            names.Add(new Triplet(
                i.ToString(), //First: ID
                "@" + taglist[i].Name, //Second: DisplayName
                //Third: Full sentence that I want in textbox
                beginning + "@" + taglist[i].Name)); 
        }
        return Json(names.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(null);
}
```

TL;DR: Is there a way to separate what is displayed in the dropdown box and what is put in the textbox on selection, with the Jquery autocomplete?

Comment: What do you mean by `just append the username to the sentence instead of replacing it completely! ` ? something like `customer[i] = { label: data[i].Third+data[i].Second, Id: data[i].First};`?

Comment: yes, but doing that will make the dropdown display the full sentence of the textbox, I only want the name to be displayed! :)